# SSL Security error when trying to connet to SQL Server 2016 from an udl test file

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

I am trying to test a SQL connection from my local PC(Win 7) to a SQL Server 2016 machine (Win 2016 Standard X64). I have just created a dummy .udl file, provided the server name, SQL credentials but I am receiving the following error:

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SecDoClientHandshake().]SSL Security error.
```

If I connect through SQL Management Studio is works.

If I try to use the ODBC tool to test data source, I am receiving the following error message in the test connection window

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.2100

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Encryption not supported on the client.
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SSL Provider: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

TESTS FAILED!
```

Update: For .udl dummy test I managed to get it work by enabling TLS 1.0 on the SQL Server System (Registry path: HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols)

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled TLS 1.0(Registry path: HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols) on the application server too so now the ODBD Data Source Test works as expected.

Comment: TLS 1.0 is deprecated, don't expect this fix to work forever

Comment: Thanks Andy for your remark...I guess the software supplier needs to update their installer and switch to a newer driver, as for now they are using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server connection to create the application's databases.

Comment: As a user of a system that's made the upgrade... I hope yours goes smoother than mine did